# Deploying Spring 3 + Hibernate app on JBoss 7 beta; Annotated Beans Not Found

Tags: java, spring, jboss

Trying to deploy my Spring 3 app on JBoss.

It is not able to find beans. Used Spring 3 annotations to declare beans.

Found zero documentation for JBoss AS 7 beta on JBoss.org so don't tell me to RTFM! :-)

Comment: Have you tried it on another appserver or servlet container? Are you shure it is related to jboss AS 7?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AS 7 is (early) beta so far, so there is no Spring deployer (-equivalent) for now.

If you found zero documentation, you did not look close enough. There is at least [developer documentation](http://community.jboss.org/en/jbossas/dev/jboss_as7_development) and the start of a [user guide](http://community.jboss.org/wiki/JBossAS7UserGuide).